# Create Oracle database link using Groovy

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, groovy

Following database link works in Toad:

```
create database link mylink
  connect to USERNAME identified by PASDWORD using '//host:port/sid';

select * from dual@mylink;
```

How can I create this link using groovy?

I tried this:

```
sql.executeUpdate('create database link mylink connect to USERNAME identified by PASSWORD using "//host:port/sid"')
```

This gives error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02010: missing host connect string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//host:port/sid should be between single quotes

Answer (score 0):

CREATE DATABASE LINK databaseglink
  CONNECT TO username
    IDENTIFIED BY password
      USING 'sid=xe host=10.0.0.32 dbname=schemaname';

Comment: You should provide some explanation with your answer